# Custom Cypher Query Restrictions - Spark Neo4j Connector

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, neo4j, cypher

Are there any limitations of writing custom cypher queries while running them through spark connector? I am using a query with call and apoc library procedures. The same query works fine in cypher shell, but fails with error -
`pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: Please provide a valid WRITE query`
when run through spark connector. Any documentation around what all are allowed in custom cypher using spark connector?

My query looks something like this -

```
WITH event.dVal as dVal, COLLECT(cVal) as cVals,
apoc.coll.toSet(apoc.coll.flatten(COLLECT(cVal.sdVals))) as sdVals
CALL {
WITH dVal, cVals, sdVals
MERGE (d:DVal {DVal:dVal})
WITH d, cVals, sdVals 
    CALL {
        WITH d, sdVals
        UNWIND sdVals as sdVal
        WITH d, sdVal
        MERGE (sd:DVal {DVal: sdVal})
        WITH d, sd
        OPTIONAL MATCH (d)-[rel3:Relation1]->(sd)
        FOREACH (o IN CASE WHEN rel3 IS NULL THEN [1] ELSE [] END |
        CREATE (d)-[:Relation1]->(sd)
        )
        RETURN sd
    }
WITH d, cVals, COLLECT(id(sd)) as sds
 CALL {
    WITH d, cVals
    UNWIND cVals as cVal
    WITH d, cVal
    MERGE (c:CVal {CId: cVal.id})
    WITH d, c, cVal
    OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[rel1:Relation2]->(d)
    FOREACH (o IN CASE WHEN rel1 IS NULL THEN [1] ELSE [] END |
    CREATE (c)-[:Relation2]->(d)
    )
 }
}
```

Comment: please show us your code. thanks.

Comment: Added my query in the question

Comment: this sounds more like a bug... please report as an issue to the repository: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-spark-connector